# react-native-google-signin/google-signIn Prompt Modal closes automatically after user chooses his account/email on Android device

Tags: android, react-native, google-signin

**A clear and concise description of what the bug is.**

When a user clicks on the GoogleSignIn Button, it loads the GoogleSignIn prompt modal for the user to select his google account.
When the user click on his account from the prompt, the modal closes automatically.
This happens on random devices as it works properly on some android devices.

I also notice that the issues happens more on the published app on playStore but works well on my development mode app when i run the app directly from my code editor.

Its really confusing since i cant figure out why the googleSignIn prompt suddenly closes after users chooses his account, thus taking the user back to the GoogleSignIn button to repeat the process again.

**Steps to reproduce the behavior:**

Click on the GoogleSignIn Button
on the Prompt modal, select/choose an account to continue
After clicking on an account to use for your signIn

The modal prompt closes. So user repeats the process again till infinity

Included links that I think may help.

**Link to app on play store**.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.betBank&hl=en&gl=US

**Link to a Video with the Bug**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K-axClCgfyfsqAjBjlFy-bD8SlmlW1lG/view?usp=sharing

**Screenshots**
[image: GoogleSignain Issue]

**A clear and concise description of what you expected to happen**.

When a user clicks on the GoogleSignIn button, he is presented with the Choose account promp-modal.
He select an account of his chooses, after which he accpets the scope of access from the marchant and
clicks on the continue button. Then the selected googleAccount info would returned from `GoogleSignin.signIn()`;

**Actual Behavior Environment**

react-native version 0.59.8

`@react-native-google-signin/google-signin` version 3.0.4

version of Android => Android 9 and other android versions

gradle => Gradle 6.2

android plugin for gradle => `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1`
`
play-services-auth => 17.0.0 and
version of the Google Play Services app on your phone (if applicable)

version of iOS (if applicable)
Happens on random Android OS version
Happens on random Android devices

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error here, mi native´s version is 0.63.2
I think that some configuration or permission is missing even though I followed the guide step by step.

Comment: cant wait to get to the buttom of this issue